# What was Duryodhana's actual name?

Tags: mahabharata, history, name, duryodhana

I have come across two opinions on this:

1. This was his actual name
2. His actual name was Suyodhana and he was later on known as Duryodhana.

What was Duryodhana's actual name?

Comment: I just did a scanned search... Mahabharat calls Duryodhan **by the name Suyodhan** 183 times... Mahabharat mentions the name **Duryodhan** 1871 times... Thus it is clear his original name was Suyodhana...

Comment: As far as I know his name was Duryodhana. The Suyodhana thing came up because people thought any name with 'Dur' means a bad thing.

Comment: @Tezz How does that number prove that Suyodhana was his original name?

Comment: @Surya I just referenced the dictionary,  Dur does mean a bad thing

Comment: I think he was called Duryodhana later on by people coz he can be considered as one of the 'villains'

Comment: @Amit No. 'Dur' means bad, but Duryodhana means 'difficult to conquer'. So the meaning of Duryodhana is 'excellent warrior'. How is that a villain's name ?

Comment: In Sanskrit there are some words which if you split and check the meaning you'll get a meaning opposite to when you combine the word.

Comment: @Surya: Ya, I just looked deeper, the dictionary also says Duryodhana means inconqeurable and Suyodahana is an epithet for Duryodhana. So, I am not sure anymore. Maybe, we should look at these things: what he was called as a child, which word is used first, when is the word Suyodhana used first

Comment: @Amit not for anything else but I will give you another example: **Durga**.

Comment: @Surya The word root there is Durg and not Dur. :) But, as I said, I am not sure anymore.

Comment: @Amit The root of Durga is also Dur - Durga is the masculine form of Durgaa. The split up would be Dur+Ga = Difficult/Bad+Accessibility = Inaccessible.

Comment: @Surya yes the root Dur means both unconquerable and also bad... I gave that number figure to show he was also called Suyodhana...

Comment: The actual name of dhritrastra's putra was Suyodhana not Duryodhana. But the writer describe him according his nature and his karma's ,So he is known as Duryodhana.

Comment: @Surya @ Tezz I think in Sanskrit we have no fixed or actual names. People are named after different attributes they possess. This is the reason, Gods and people in Hindu mythology have many names.

Comment: @TheDestroyer That is a good reasoning for the Gods, but I think in cases of historical characters, they would have had some name, given by their parents. An example would be King Bharata, whose given name was Sarvadamana, but was called Bharata after the divine voice proclaimed his right to the throne of Hastinapura. So though Bharata was a situation based name, Sarvadamana would have been chosen at his birth.

Answer (score 7):

Both are names for the same person and often used interchangeably. [Suyodhan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duryodhana) means one who is good with arms (in warfare). Duryodhan means unconquerable warrior. Naturally there can be many who are good in battle but there can be only ONE who is unconquerable, by definition. Duryodhan was more unique and it stuck.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. *His actual name was Suyodhana and he was later on known as Duryodhana.*

It's the other way round as Nityānanda Miśra clarifies in a series of tweets starting with [this](https://twitter.com/MisraNityanand/status/1204460718445121536). He's referring to [this verse](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs04060.htm) from Virāṭa Parva where Arjuna taunts Duryodhana saying his former name, *Duryodhana* (which literally means *one who is difficult to fight with*) doesn't suit him as he's running away from the battlefield.

> 18  moghaṃ tavedaṃ bhuvi nāmadheyaṃ; duryodhanetīha kṛtaṃ purastāt 
>        na hīha duryodhanatā tavāsti; palāyamānasya raṇaṃ vihāya
>
> Arjuna said,
>
> > Renounce your deeds and great fame. Why are you running away in this way and refraining from battle? Why aren't trumpets being sounded for you now, the way they were sounded when you set out to do battle? I obediently follow Yudhishthira's instructions. I am the third of the Parthas and I am steadfast in battle. Therefore, turn around and show me your face. O son of Dhritarashtra! Remember how Indras among men are supposed to act. **You have been named Duryodhana earlier, but that name will be uttered on earth in vain**.<sup>194</sup> **There is no Duryodhana left in you. You are running away and refraining from battle**. I do not see anyone to protect Duryodhana, either at the front or at the back. O foremost among Kurus! Therefore, run away from the battle. Protect your beloved life from the Pandava.
>
> <sup>194</sup> <sub>Duryodhana means someone who it is difficult to fight with.</sub>
>
> ([Bibek Debroy. The Mahabharata: Volume 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XY9DTBD))

Another twitter user True Indology [argues](https://twitter.com/TIinExile/status/1204599376737263617) that it's mostly Duryodhana's rivals that address him as "Suyodhana" meaning "easy to be fought".

> In Mahabharata, it is his rivals like Yudhisthira, Bhima, Arjuna, Krishna, Bhishma, Dhrishtadyumna, Nakula, etc., as well as sages like Narada, Kanva, Vaisampayana, etc., who refer to Duryodhana as "Suyodhana".
>
> **Why?**
>
> "Suyodhana" means "one who can be easily defeated in war".
>
> Benfey Sanskrit-English Dictionary:
>
> [सुयोधन suyodhana](https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/BENScan/2020/web/webtc/servepdf.php?page=1050-a), i. e. su-yudh + ana, m. A name of Duryodhana (**easy to be fought**), Hiḍ. 4, 58.
>
> [दुर्योधन duryodhana](https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/BENScan/2020/web/webtc/servepdf.php?page=0407-b) (see the next), m. The eldest of the Kuru princes, MBh. 1, 2728.
>
> दुर्योधनता duryodhana + tā, i. e. dus-yudh + ana + tā, f. **Difficulty of being attacked**, MBh. 4, 2103.